# Замена Alert на свое окно

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть вот такой код

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var inst = $('[data-remodal-id=modal]').remodal();
    $('#modal').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        inst.open();
    });

    if ($('#sendautor').length) {
        inst.open();
    }

});
```

Он вызывает модальное окно.

Как мне его встроить вместо alert. alert срабатывает вот так:

```
if(res.z< min || res.v> max) {
    alert('Incorrectly');
    return false;
}
```

То есть чтобы вместо `alert('Incorrectly');` выполнилась вот эта функция:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var inst = $('[data-remodal-id=modal]').remodal();
    $('#modal').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        inst.open();
    });

    if ($('#sendautor').length) {
        inst.open();
    }

});
```

Вроде бы вопрос понятен...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос не ясен. Если я вас правильно понял, то просто [перепишите функцию alert](http://jsfiddle.net/alvoro/yks7hdv2/).